# WordPress ACF - Required field based on other fields imput

Tags: json, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the ACF plugin on my website and need a situation in which a certain field is ONLY required when other fields are not empty. In this particular case the field ‘Title’ is not required. However when one of the following fields are not empty it has to be required: Deal or Discount, Description, Regular Price, Discounted price / deal price and Valid until. I need this situation because either all fields need to be empty or all field need to be filled.

This is the json code I created so far:

```
[
    {
        "key": "group_deal1",
        "title": "Deal 1 test 2 (displayed on homepage)",
        "fields": [
            {
                "key": "field_deal1title",
                "label": "Title",
                "name": "deal_title_one_test1",
                "type": "text",
                "instructions": "(max. 100 characters)",
                "required": [
                    [
                        {
                            "field": "field_deal1dealdiscount",
                            "operator": "!=empty"
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        {
                            "field": "field_deal1description",
                            "operator": "!=empty"
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        {
                            "field": "field_deal1regularprice",
                            "operator": "!=empty"
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        {
                            "field": "field_deal1discountedprice",
                            "operator": "!=empty"
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        {
                            "field": "field_deal1validdate",
                            "operator": "!=empty"
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "conditional_logic": 0,
                "wrapper": {
                    "width": "",
                    "class": "deals-title",
                    "id": ""
                },
                "default_value": "",
                "placeholder": "",
                "prepend": "",
                "append": "",
                "maxlength": 100
            },
            {
                "key": "field_deal1dealdiscount",
                "label": "Deal or Discount",
                "name": "discount_deal_or_special_one",
                "type": "radio",
                "instructions": "",
                "required": 0,
                "conditional_logic": 0,
                "wrapper": {
                    "width": "",
                    "class": "",
                    "id": ""
                },
                "choices": {
                    "Discount": "Discount",
                    "Deal": "Deal"
                },
                "allow_null": 1,
                "other_choice": 0,
                "default_value": "",
                "layout": "vertical",
                "return_format": "value",
                "save_other_choice": 0
            },
            {
                "key": "field_deal1description",
                "label": "Description",
                "name": "deal_description_one",
                "type": "textarea",
                "instructions": "(max. 600 characters)",
                "required": 0,
                "conditional_logic": 0,
                "wrapper": {
                    "width": "",
                    "class": "deals-description",
                    "id": ""
                },
                "default_value": "",
                "placeholder": "",
                "maxlength": 600,
                "rows": "",
                "new_lines": ""
            },
            {
                "key": "field_deal1regularprice",
                "label": "Regular price",
                "name": "regular_price_one",
                "type": "number",
                "instructions": "",
                "required": 0,
                "conditional_logic": 0,
                "wrapper": {
                    "width": "",
                    "class": "deals-regular-price",
                    "id": ""
                },
                "default_value": "",
                "placeholder": "",
                "prepend": "$",
                "append": "",
                "min": "",
                "max": "",
                "step": ""
            },
            {
                "key": "field_deal1discountedprice",
                "label": "Discounted price \/ deal price",
                "name": "discounted_price_one",
                "type": "number",
                "instructions": "",
                "required": 0,
                "conditional_logic": 0,
                "wrapper": {
                    "width": "",
                    "class": "deals-discounted-price",
                    "id": ""
                },
                "default_value": "",
                "placeholder": "",
                "prepend": "$",
                "append": "",
                "min": "",
                "max": "",
                "step": ""
            },
            {
                "key": "field_deal1validdate",
                "label": "Valid until",
                "name": "valid_until_one",
                "type": "date_picker",
                "instructions": "",
                "required": 0,
                "conditional_logic": 0,
                "wrapper": {
                    "width": "",
                    "class": "",
                    "id": ""
                },
                "display_format": "m\/d\/Y",
                "return_format": "m\/d\/Y",
                "first_day": 1
            }
        ],
        "location": [
            [
                {
                    "param": "post_type",
                    "operator": "==",
                    "value": "post"
                },
                {
                    "param": "post_format",
                    "operator": "==",
                    "value": "aside"
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "param": "post_format",
                    "operator": "==",
                    "value": "status"
                }
            ]
        ],
        "menu_order": 1,
        "position": "acf_after_title",
        "style": "default",
        "label_placement": "top",
        "instruction_placement": "label",
        "hide_on_screen": "",
        "active": 1,
        "description": ""
    }
]
```

It doen’t work.. It gives me a result in which the field Title is required at all times.

Hopefully someone can help. Thank you in advance!

PS. I know how to hide fields with conditional logic but that doesn’t empty the fields and therefor will still be visible on the website. So another solution would be to empty the fields when the Title is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an if else statement around the fields you want to hide front end? IE

```
<?php 
$dealfield1 = get_field( 'field_deal1dealdiscount' );
$dealfield2 = get_field( 'field_deal1description');
$dealfield3 = get_field( 'field_deal1regularprice');
$dealfield4 = get_field( 'field_deal1discountedprice');

if( !empty($dealfield1) || !empty($dealfield2) || !empty($dealfield3) || !empty($dealfield4) ): ?>
    <h1> <?php the_field('title'); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then as you mentioned in the last part of your post you could use conditional logic to hide the field when necessary.

Or perhaps you could add a true false field which could use conditional logic to hide the fields back end and a simpler if else on the template page.

```
<?php if( get_field('new_true_false_field') ): ?>
    <p>My field value: <?php the_field('title'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```